# How can I fix my code to run only once in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var timeToJoin = '18:13';
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes();

var SST = 'https://meet.google.com/rnc-akmx-ubk';

if (time == timeToJoin) {
    joinClass();
}

function joinClass() {
    location.href = SST;
    setTimeout(offMicVideo, 10000);
}

function offMicVideo() {
    var video = document.getElementsByClassName('I5fjHe');
    var mic = document.getElementsByClassName('oTVIqe');

    for (var i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
        video[i].click();
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < mic.length; i++) {
        mic[i].click();
    }
}
```

This is an extension which automatically joins meet at time But you have surely  noticed a small problem in this `if (time == timeToJoin) {` condition whats happening here is when the correct time comes the extension tries to join the meeting but according to the if condition it tries to join the meeting every second till the if condition matches .

Please give me some solution to run the function inside the if statement **only once**.

Comment: Just set a variable as true after the first time code has run, then check it in the condition.

Answer (score 2):

This seems as simple as using another mechanism to ensure that the class is only joined once.

My recommendation would be to use a flag to indicate this, as so:

```
// Declare hasJoined outside of your looped code
var hasJoined = false;

// Inside your looped code
...
var SST = 'https://meet.google.com/rnc-akmx-ubk';

if (!hasJoined && time == timeToJoin) {
    hasJoined = true;
    joinClass();
}
...
```

The variable `hasJoined` must be declared outside of your loop code that monitors for the time.  Otherwise you would overwrite the result each time the loop ran.

This works simply by checking that `hasJoined` is false before attempting to join the class.  If `hasJoined` has not been set and it is time to join the class, `hasJoined` will be set and the `joinClass()` function will execute.

Changing `hasJoined` to true then prevents multiple attempts to join the class.

Comment: Shouldn't it be === since this is a JavaScript comparison.

Comment: @TheFunk Should what be?  I haven't added any equality operators at all to the code, so it reproduces OP's original code

Comment: That's exactly what I suggested in my comment. I've upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your `if` statement inside a time interval of 1 minute so it will check your condition only after 1 minute interval and will also reduce the unnecessary execution of code.

> Considering the case that 1 minute late is allowed in the meeting :)